# Primitive function of $ \frac{1}{z} $

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $ U_1,U_2,U_3,U_4 \subset \mathbb{C} $ be the upper, lower,right and left open half-planes with respect to the axes (for example $ U_{1}=\left\{ z:Im\left(Z\right)>0\right\}  $ ).

Show that the function $ f(z) =  \frac{1}{z} $ has a primitive on each union of one, two or three of the half-planes $U_i $, but not on the union of all four.

Im not sure how to find $ F $ such that for all, say $ z\in U_{1}\cup U_{2}\cup U_{3} $, the following holds:$$ F'\left(z\right)=\frac{1}{z} $$

What I do know how to do, is for each, say, $ a\in U_{1}\cup U_{2}\cup U_{3} $, to find a neigborhood where $f(z) $ has primitive, but that is not what I need.

I would highly appreciate help here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The union of any three halfplanes is *simply connected.*

Comment: @MartinR Okay, and how can I find a primitive? I only know to use the fact that $ 1/z $ is analytic in neighborhood that does not include $ 0 $ and then find primitive at the disk with small enough radius so that $ 0 $ would not be in the disk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to show there exists a branch of logarithm in these domains. For example, let's look at $U_1\cup U_2\cup U_3$, which is just $\mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty, 0]$. In this domain we have the principal branch of the argument function, which is the argument in the interval $(-\pi, \pi)$. This principal branch is usually denoted by $Arg(z)$. This allows us to define a branch of logarithm $Log: \mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty, 0]\to\mathbb{C}$ by:

$Log(z)=ln|z|+iArg(z)$

It is well known that branches of logarithm are holomorphic, and the derivative is $\frac{1}{z}$.

Comment: What do you mean by “branch”?

Comment: The complex exponential function is not injective, and so we can't easily define a complex logarithm like in the real case. In order to define a logarithm function, at each point $z$ of our domain we have to choose some specific value $w$ which satisfies $e^w=z$. A branch of logarithm is such a choice of values for which our logarithm function is continuous. It is not something we can do in all domains, but for example, in $\mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty, 0]$ there exists a branch of logarithm. Actually, I'm not sure how you are supposed to solve this problem if you don't know about branches.

Comment: I See. I Tried to read about it, my last question, that would make it a lot more clear - how your choice of U1, U2 or U3 can he seen in the choice to work with the principal branch $ (-\pi,\pi)$ ? What if we would choose arg(Z) such that the allowed angles would be in $ (0,2\pi)$ ?

Comment: In that case we would have problems at points in the interval $(0,\infty)$. Suppose $x\in (0,\infty)$. At points a bit above $x$ the argument is very close to $0$, while at points a bit below $x$ the argument is very close to $2\pi$. So this argument function would not be continuous at the point $x$. On the other hand, when we work with arguments in $(-\pi, \pi)$ then the problematic points are at the interval $(-\infty, 0)$. But it doesn't matter to us, because we work in $U_1\cup U_2\cup U_3=\mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty, 0]$, so in this case the problematic points are not part of our domain.

Comment: For the same reason, when we work in $U_1\cup U_2\cup U_4=\mathbb{C}\setminus [0,\infty)$ then we indeed choose the argument in $(0,2\pi)$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a general argument.

Primitives (of a holomorphic function $f : U \to \mathbb C$ on a connected subdomain of $U$) are unique up to an additive constant. So if you know primitives $F_1$, $F_2$, $F_3$ on connected domains $U_1$, $U_2$, $U_3 \subset U$, and if $U_1 \cup U_2 \cup U_3$ is connected, and if you know that a primitive exists on $U_1 \cup U_2 \cup U_3$ (for example if you know that $U_1 \cup U_2 \cup U_3$ is simply connected), then you can compute a formula for a primitive on $U_1 \cup U_2 \cup U_3$. The formula will have the form
$$F(z) = 
\begin{cases}
F_1(z) + C_1 &\quad\text{if $z \in U_1$} \\
F_2(z) + C_2 &\quad\text{if $z \in U_2$} \\
F_3(z) + C_3 &\quad\text{if $z \in U_3$}
\end{cases}
$$
but the constants $C_1,C_2,C_3$ must be specified. You can choose $C_1$ arbitrarily (e.g. $C_1=0$), and then $C_2$ and $C_3$ are determined. You can compute $C_2,C_3$ by exploiting the fact that at least two of the three intersections $U_1 \cap U_2$ or $U_2 \cap U_3$ or $U_3 \cap U_1$ are nonempty. For instance, if there exists $w \in U_1 \cap U_2$ then $F(w)=F_1(w)+C_1=F_2(w)+C_2$ and therefore $C_2 = F_1(w)-F_2(w)+C_1$.